# What's creating NaNs in OpenACC code?

Tags: loops, fortran, nan, fortran90, openacc

I need to instrument a Fortran code with OpenACC.  Here are the relevant portions:

```
program myprogram


real :: x(160,100,100,8)
!$acc declare create(x(:,:,:,:))
integer, parameter :: ns1=1
integer, parameter :: ns2=8
integer, parameter :: nx=160
!$acc declare create(ns1,ns2,nx)   ! apparently I don't need this line?

! lots of stuff happens to define x and plenty of
! other things, then …

subroutine myroutine(id1,id2)

real xin(160,8)

!$acc update device(x(:,:,:,:))

!$acc data copyin(id1,id2,taskid) create(xin(:,:))

!debug
      print *, 'in dat',taskid,x(80,id1,id2,1),x(81,id1,id2,1),x(82,id1,id2,1)
! define new arrays for velocity and density

!$acc parallel num_gangs(8) vector_length(160)
!debug
      print *, 'in par',taskid,x(80,id1,id2,1),x(81,id1,id2,1),x(82,id1,id2,1)

!$acc loop gang
      do ni = ns1,ns2
!$acc loop vector
        do i = 1,nx
          xin(i,ni) = x(i,id1,id2,ni)
        enddo
      enddo
!debug
      print *, 'xin vals',taskid,xin(80,1),xin(81,1),xin(82,1)

!$acc end parallel

!$acc end data

end subroutine


end program
```

When I examine the output from the "in dat" lines, and then from the "in par" lines, the numbers look reasonable.  When I examine the "xin vals" lines, I see several NaNs.  Not all NaNs, but several.  The assignment of xin is so simple!  What could have possibly gone wrong?  (And in case you haven't guessed, I'm pretty new to OpenACC.  Thanks.)

EDIT: This compiled with PGI Fortran.

Comment: Use tag Fortran for better visibility. There is nothing Fortran 90 specific in the question.

Comment: @Vladimir F     OK, Thanks for the tip!

Comment: since xin has NaNs, then probably 'x' has nans. You could check values in x to see if there are Nans there

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what your compiler (you don't say which one) is doing, but certainly implementing `print` inside an `parallel` region is non-trivial.  What results to you see if you move the debugging `print`s outside of the parallel region (outside of the `data` region, in fact)?  Instead of `create(xin(:,:))` you'll then want to use a `copyout` clause, so that you can inspect the data on the host, after the `data` region.

Comment: @techwinge  I guess i could have shown that, but my print statements outside of the data region show good data, no NaNs.  Examining the data after the data region (again, i didn't show here) shows that the NaNs are copied back to the host, consistently with how they appear in the data region.  Trying to figure out where those NaNs were coming from was in fact what got me started on this.  And by the way I am compiling with PGI.